# How to run a polling blocking consumer in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blocking, java.util.concurrent

I have some service that both consumes from an inbound queue and produces to some outbound queue (where another thread, created by this service, picks up the messages and "transports" them to their destination).

Currently I use two plain `Thread`s as seen in the code bellow but I know that in general you should not use them anymore and instead use the higher level abstractions like the `ExecutorService`.

Would this make sense in my case? More specifically I mean ->

- would it reduce code?
- make the code more robust in case of failure?
- allow for smoother thread termination? (which is helpfull when running tests)

Am I missing something important here? (maybee some other classes from *java.util.concurrent*)

```
// called on service startup
private void init() {
    // prepare everything here
    startInboundWorkerThread();
    startOutboundTransporterWorkerThread();
}

private void startInboundWorkerThread() {
    InboundWorkerThread runnable = injector.getInstance(InboundWorkerThread.class);
    inboundWorkerThread = new Thread(runnable, ownServiceIdentifier);
    inboundWorkerThread.start();
}

// this is the Runnable for the InboundWorkerThread 
// the runnable for the transporter thread looks almost the same
@Override
public void run() {       
    while (true) {
        InboundMessage message = null;
        TransactionStatus transaction = null;

        try {
            try {
                transaction = txManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // logging
                break;
            }

            // blocking consumer
            message = repository.takeOrdered(template, MESSAGE_POLL_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
            if (message != null) {                   
                handleMessage(message);
                commitTransaction(message, transaction);
            } else {
                commitTransaction(transaction);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // logging
            rollback(transaction);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // logging
            rollback(transaction);
            throw e;
        }

        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            // logging
            break;
        }
    }

    // logging
}

// called when service is shutdown
// both inbound worker thread and transporter worker thread must be terminated
private void interruptAndJoinWorkerThread(final Thread workerThread) {
    if (workerThread != null && workerThread.isAlive()) {
        workerThread.interrupt();

        try {
            workerThread.join(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // logging
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit for me in using ThreadPools comes from structuring the work in single, independent and usually short jobs and better abstraction of threads in a `ThreadPool`s private `Worker`s. Sometimes you may want more direct access to those, to find out if they are still running etc. But there are usually better, *job-centric* ways to do that.

As for handling failures, you may want to submit your own `ThreadFactory` to create threads with a custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and in general, your `Runnable` jobs should provide good exception handling, too, in order to log more information about the specific job that failed.
Make those jobs non-blocking, since you don't want to fill up your ThreadPool with blocked workers. Move blocking operations before the job is queued.

Normally, `shutdown` and `shutdownNow` as provided by `ExecutorService`s, combined with proper interrupt handling in your jobs will allow for smooth job termination.